# How to serialize an anonymous type to JSON, when JSON *needs* properties with characters like dashes '-' e.t.c

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, serialization

I am building an app that uses Open Flash Chart 2. This chart is a flash object that accepts JSON with a specific structure.

```
"elements": [
{
    "type": "bar_stack",
    "colours": [
        "#F19899",
        "#A6CEE3"
    ],
    "alpha": 1,
    "on-show": {
        "type": "grow-up",
        "cascade": 1,
        "delay": 0
    },
    ...
```

I am using a simple anonymous type to return the JSON like so:

```
return Json(new
{
    elements = new [] {
        new
        {
            type = "bar_stack",
            colours = colours.Take(variables.Count()),
            alpha = 1,
            on_show = new
            {
                type = "grow-up",
                cascade = 1,
                delay = 0
            },
            ...
        }
}
```

The problem is that several properties (like "on-show") use a dash and obviously I cannot use a dash when naming a property in C# code.

Is there a way to overcome this? Preferably without the need to declare a whole bunch of classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary:

```
return Json(new {
    elements = new [] {
        new Dictionary<string, object> 
        { 
            { "type", "bar_stack" },
            { "colours", new [] { "#F19899", "#A6CEE3" } },
            { "alpha", 1 },
            { "on-show", new 
                         {
                             type = "grow-up",
                             cascade = 1,
                             delay = 0
                         } },
        } 
    }
});
```

(Written in SO editor; I may have made some syntax errors, but you get the idea....)

Comment: Although I ended up keeping my own solution, I think yours is a better approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Craig's solution is propably better, but in the meantime I implemented this:

```
public class UnderscoreToDashAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string[] _fixes;

    public UnderscoreToDashAttribute(params string[] fixes)
    {
        _fixes = fixes;
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Filter = new ReplaceFilter(filterContext, s => _fixes.Aggregate(s, (current, fix) => current.Replace(fix, fix.Replace('_', '-'))));
    }

    public class ReplaceFilter : MemoryStream
    {
        private readonly Stream _stream;
        private readonly Func<string, string> _filter;

        public ReplaceFilter(ControllerContext filterContext, Func<string, string> filter)
        {
            _stream = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Filter;
            _filter = filter;
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
             // capture the data and convert to string 
            var data = new byte[count];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, offset, data, 0, count);

            var s = _filter(Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer));

            // write the data to stream 
            var outdata = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s);
            _stream.Write(outdata, 0, outdata.GetLength(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, if you decorate your action like so:

```
[UnderscoreToDash("on_show", "grid_colour")]
public JsonResult GetData()
```

It makes the appropriate "fixes".

P.S. That awesome moment when Resharper changes your code to Linq...

```
_fixes.Aggregate(s, (current, fix) => current.Replace(fix, fix.Replace('_', '-')))
```